# Outlook 2010 Addin not shown

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in, hidden, outlook-2010

I have an interesting problem: After finally having managed to actually make Outlook load the addin after its installation (the addin is a form extension for the new-item inspector), Outlook does not show the form.

On the computer I developed it, running Visual Studio, everything works just fine, but when trying to install it on another computer, the addin is installed, and during the startup screen, Outlook is showing that the addin is loading, and in the Options->Addins menu, the addin is shown as a (not-disabled) COM-addin. However, when creating a new email or other item, the form that is supposed to be at the bottom is not shown. How come, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

some problem with your setup process steps.Even,I too faced the same.If dll is not picked,it will cause this issue.
Try to follow the steps given in this link 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/10/01/building-and-deploying-an-outlook-2010-add-in-part-2-of-2.aspx

create a proper folder while creating registry,
Eg:Microsoft-->office-->Outlook-->AddIns-->your Addin Name.

If yu miss one folder even,addin wont get populated.

Try these and let me know.